# How to set user environment variable in syslinux mboot.c32 boot loader

Tags: bootstrap-4, centos, fedora, boot, syslinux

I need to set a user environment variable in syslinux mboot.c32 boot menu, and then read it back when I am in the OS.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set kernel command line variables in the APPEND line (similar to `root=/dev/sda1` and `console=tty0`), and the whole kernel command line is available after boot in `/proc/cmdline`.  A tiny `sed` script could turn that into an environment variable.